# 3d: octomap or PCL (pointcloud lib)?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I am trying to have the navigation stack running and generate a 3d map; after using octomap, I got something like this:

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

The robot as if is going through a wall. The 2d map is self correcting itself in realtime, while the 3d map generated by octomap is not; the marker array published by octomap will never be update or erased.

So I am wondering, is PCL an alternative for doing 3d mapping?

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66724/3d:-octomap-or-pcl-(pointcloud-lib)?/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PCL is a library, so it doesn't have many fully working demos that are very advanced (demos are best kept simple, so the code is understandable). There are several other real 3D slam packages -- for instance CCNY's code (https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_rgbd_tools) or RGBD_SLAM (a couple others are listed on blog post I made a while back: http://www.showusyoursensors.com/2013/02/3d-mapping-is-here.html).

However --- it appears you are in simulation -- and most of these packages use 2d-like features (things that would probably depend on actual, real texture being in the images received) and will probably not work in Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-07-10**:
you are the man!